# Compact Framework Thread ends in background --> Performance issue

Tags: multithreading, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm developing a win forms application for Windows CE based devices.

I have to initialize all controls my dialog shows at runtime because I get the information about the UI layout from a backend system via WLAN every time the user performs an action on the screen.

The performance is not the best but it's ok in most cases. But sometime there is a thread in background that ends and the next function call in main thread needs 300-400 ms to return.

In debugger I can see the thread ID from the thread that ends. Is there any way to find out which thread is associated with this thread ID, so that I could keep the thread alive until the application is in an time uncritical part?
I think it's a thread from an UI element because I don't start threads manually.

Comment: If you did not create the thread and named it, it will be hard to find out which object created the thread. You may add some debug output before and after each UI object you load. Possibly show some code here.

Comment: Please share some source to help you.